# Detect numbers in string

Tags: python

```
value = 'ad.41.bd'

if len(value) == len(value.strip({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})):
    # no numbers
else:
    # numbers present
```

There a cleaner way of detecting numbers in a string in Python?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about this?

```
import re
if not re.search('\d+', value):
    # no numbers
else:
    # numbers present
```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> value="ab3asdf"
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in value)
True
>>> value="asf"
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in value)
False




>>> value = 'ad.41.bd'
>>> any(map(lambda c:c.isdigit(),value))
True
```

EDIT:

```
>>> value="1"+"a"*10**6
>>> any(map(lambda c:c.isdigit(),value))
True
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> any(imap(lambda c:c.isdigit(),value))
True
```

map took 1 second (on old python)
imap was instant because imap returns a generator. note often in the real world there is a higher probability of the number being at the end of the file name.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how good (or bad) this performs compared to a regex.

Comment: I like `any`, but `map` generates the entire list first. If `value` is huge and the first character is a digit, this code still processes the whole thing.

Comment: I believe any stops when it finds the first True. However map doesn't return a generator (apart from I think in python 3) so a whole list is created in memory (even if the first character is a digit). Otherwise I'm guessing it would be fairly similar.

Comment: @robert king: it should read `c.isdigit()` (note the parens). Also, I agree with @Kirk Strauser. Better would be `itertools.imap` or a _generator expression_.

Comment: @mhyfritz I added in imap just before. Thanks for the tip on the parens I added them in, what difference does it make (it still worked without)?

Comment: @robert king, w/o the parens you create a list of _methods_. This will always evaluate to `True`! Try it with `value = 'abc'`.

Comment: `bool(c.isdigit)` is always true because `c.isdigit` isn't [one of the values of False](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html). Without parenthesis, your map function creates a list list `[<built-in method isdigit ...>, <built-in method isdigit ...>]` without actually executing the function.

Comment: `any(c.isdigit() for c in value)` uses a generator expression and dispenses with the lambda and the map.

Answer (score 4):

```
from string import digits
def containsnumbers(value):
    return any(char in digits for char in value)
```

#### EDIT:

And just for thoroughness:

any(c.isdigit()):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('any(c.isdigit() for c in value)', setup='value = "abcd1"')
1.4080650806427002
```

any(c in digits):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('any(c in digits for c in value)', setup='from string import digits; value = "abcd1"')
1.392179012298584
```

re.search (1 or more digits):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("re.search('\d+', value)", setup='import re; value = "abcd1"')
1.8129329681396484
```

re.search (stop after one digit):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("re.search('\d', value)", setup='import re; value = "abcd1"')
1.599431037902832
```

re.match (non-greedy):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("re.match(r'^.*?\d', value)", setup='import re; value = "abcd1"')
1.6654980182647705
```

re.match(greedy):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("re.match(r'^.*\d', value)", setup='import re; value = "abcd1"')
1.5637178421020508
```

any(map()):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("any(map(lambda c:c.isdigit(),value))", setup='value = "abcd1"')
1.9165890216827393
```

any(imap()):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("any(imap(lambda c:c.isdigit(),value))", setup='from itertools import imap;value = "abcd1"')
1.370448112487793
```

Generally, the less complex regexps ran more quickly. `c.isdigit()` and `c in digits` are almost equivalent. `re.match` is slightly faster than `re.search`. `map()` is the slowest solution, but `imap()` was the fastest (but within rounding error of `any(c.isdigit)` and `any(c in digits)`.

Comment: I played with your timings and found that as the value increases in length the regexes perform better and better.

Comment: @Steven: That seems reasonable as it shifts a lot of the work to C. I changed `value` to `"abcd" * 1000 + "9"` and decreased `number` to 10000. `any(imap)` took 7.588s, `re.search` (stop after first match) took 0.377s, and `any(c in digits)` took 4.283s. Rewriting the last as `any(d in value for d in digits)` took only .310s (and .073s when the last digit was "1" instead of "9"), again I suppose because it pushed most of the workload to off to core.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re
# or if re.search(r'\d', value):
if re.match(r'^.*?\d', value):
    # numbers present
else:
    # no numbers
```

Comment: You don't need to anchor the expression with `^` and would probably be better off with `re.search`. Also, `.*` matches zero or more characters so `?` is redundant.

Comment: @Kirk: I thought `search` might look for *all* locations that match this pattern (by I need only one), whereas `match` will only match at the beginning (so yes, I could omit `^` here). I want the shortest possible match, hence the `.*?` (not greedy).

Comment: Good points. After I've slept a little and had some coffee, I'll re-evaluate. :-)

Comment: `search` give only the first match.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not any(c.isdigit() for c in value)
    # no numbers
else:
    # numbers present
```

Answer (score 1):

*To detect signs in the numbers*, use the `?` operator.

```
import re
if not re.search('-?\d+', value):
    # no numbers
else:
    # numbers present
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how big is the difference, you can use re.sub()

> ```
> import re
> digits_num = len(value) - len(re.sub(r'\d','',value))
> if not digits_num:
>     #without numbers
> else:
>     #with numbers - or elif digist_num == 3
> ```